# Should hierarchical clustering be used to compare the similarity of censored data?

Tags: clustering, similarities, censoring, hierarchical-clustering

I have some samples that have been treated with various chemical agents. Users score the treatment effect using categorical values / bins (i.e., $< 1, 2.5, 8, ..., > 100$). Within a range of say 1-100 they can get some fairly precise metrical information but outside of that range they input greater or less than the limit values. So if a user wants to know how similar one sample is to another, I could do some sort of hierarchical clustering.  But I'm wondering, given this type of mixed data,

- What distance metric would be suitable?
- What could be an alternative clustering approach?
- Are there alternative methods to clustering?

Comment: How many data do you have in total, & how many fall in the two censored categories?